# How do genetic chimeras with different blood types not die?

Tags: dna, hematology, autoimmune, chimerism

If a person is a chimera and has two different blood types in his veins, how does he not die? Shouldn't the immune system attack one of the blood types?

> In 1953 a human chimera was reported in the British Medical Journal. A
>   woman was found to have blood containing two different blood types.
>   Apparently this resulted from her twin brother's cells living in her
>   body. More recently, a study found that such blood group chimerism
>   is not rare.

Comment: Can you please give a reference for this happening?

Comment: This is particularly true for the marmoset. Recent research shows most marmosets are chimeras, sharing DNA with their fraternal twins.[5] 95% of Marmoset fraternal twins trade blood through chorionic fusions, making them hematopoietic chimeras.[6][7]

Comment: @Chris Taken from wiki page for chimerism

Comment: If they have both antigens from the beginning, they won't develop antibodies to them.

Comment: That's like people who have bloodgroup AB - if they have this from the beginning, they develop no antibodies.

Answer (score 3):

Since these cells are there by the development of the immune system, the immune cells recognize them as self. By blood transfusion with incompatible blood type, the immune system recognizes the blood cells with different histocompatibility antigens (A,B,Rh etc...) as non-self, that's why it attacks them.